# close Browser from code behind - aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this aspx page and it works all fine.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string clientID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
   string clientName = Request.QueryString["NAME"];
   folderSearch(clientID, clientName);
}
public void folderSearch(string clientID, string clientName)
{
    SYS.getInfo(searchDBInfo => 
   {
        string folderPath = searchDBInfo.sPath + "\\" + clientID + " - " + clientName;
        if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            Process.Start(folderPath);
        }
        else
        {
           Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
           Process.Start(folderPath);
        }
   });
}
```

I would like the aspx running browser window to be closed straight after it displayed. means user should not be able to see any browser running but it can still do its job in background.

Please help me guys! Thanks.

Comment: "means user should not be able to see any browser running but it can still do its job in background" - er... you want a hidden browser? just: no. And again: no. If you want to keep processing things *at the server*: sure; no problem. Also: you can only "close" a browser at the client; the code-behind happens at the server.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like the aspx running browser window to be closed straight
>   after it displayed. means user should not be able to see any browser
>   running but it can still do its job in background.

It is not in your control, it is a browser function, and you can't do anything about it.

Comment: I came across a method windows.close() in silverlight using c#. Does anything similar not exist here with aspx? but ofcourse it asks for user's input for Yes or No (which again I dont want)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to do this is by Javascript (client side) with window.close() and you'll have a prompt showing you "Do you want to close this window" .

One solution would be to "close" after display is to redirect after a sleep and you'll not have the prompt.

Note : The page won't show up if your server-side code is not finished.